# Swift modifying table outside of tableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, static

I am new to Swift and iOS development and I wanted to see if there was a better way to accomplish the following:

In my app I have a table which is stored as an [someObject] and managed by a tableViewController.  I wrote all of the logic for managing the table in the tableViewController (adding objects, removing objects, etc).  However, the tableView itself, will only have the ability to delete objects from the table.  I would like to add the keys programmatically from a different part of the application.  The trouble with this is accessing the array which represents the table from outside the tableViewController.

The best solution that I have thought of is making the array static so that I can modify it without having an instance of the tableViewController (the tableViewController is not going to be on the navigation stack when objects need to be added to the table).

I don't want to segue to the tableViewController either.  The addition to the table should happen behind the scenes.

Like I said, I am new to Swift and iOS development so I wanted to see if there was a better way to accomplish this.  I would prefer not to use statics if I don't have to.

Comment: You're trying to reinvent the wheel. Have a data source. The TVC gets the data (directly from the source or through a custom class that sets up the data for the table) and creates the table. Elsewhere in your code, you can update the data source (again, either by accessing the data source directly, or through the managing class.)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a static Array but you shouldn't have also multiple classes managing the same object.
Your Array should be managed by a Manager class, and this manager can be accessible by multiple classes. Your tableViewController shouldn't have the ability to delete objects but call the manager that would perform these changes

Comment: Why is this better?  I am still going to have to either make the manager class static or pass it through the navigation stack.  In my current setup I have the tableViewController doing all the work, the other class would just have to call a method to add an object to the table.

Comment: The Manager can be static, but you also can inject reference to your manager to controllers which need to access it. Your Array shouldn't be accessible and should be private/fileprivate (the setter has to be private, for the getter, as you want).
The need to use a manager to manage your data (your Array here) is to simplify your code reading (you know your data are modified in one class only, can't be modified from another), allow easily testing (you can write tests easily as you don't have to manage your view inside) and allow you to reuse your code anywhere as it has no dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do more than you have to. Apple built UITableViewControllers with a lot of the functionality you are looking for built right in.

First in your storyboard add a label to the cell with a tag of 123. Then another viewController with an empty array that is compatible with the array from the tableViewController.

In the identity inspector for each viewController make sure that you add the file name and hit enter.

Also setup the reuseidentifier by looking at the attributes for the tableViewCell in the main.storyboard enter "cell"(no quotes) into the field Identifier.

Start with tableViewController1 display your array(I'm assuming it's preloaded. You made no mention otherwise) using the datasource methods

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return yourObjects.list.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    let label = cell.viewWithTag(123) as? UILabel
    label?.text = yourObjects.list[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

I highly recommend using a navigationController if you are not going to use segues. They are a major part of the "iOS experience" and make the task you are trying to accomplish much easier. There are many ways to do this but this is a fairly simple one. 
In your delegate methods

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let yourNextVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "nextVC") as! TheNextVC
    navigationController?.pushViewController(yourNextVC, animated: true)
    yourNextVC.arrayName = yourObjects.list[indexPath.row]
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
}
```

This last method is where your array gets passed from this table to the next viewController where you can edit it or do what ever you'd like.